# Generate JAX-WS classes from WSDL file using Maven plugin with Java11

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jax-ws, java-11

In Java 11, JAX-WS has been removed from the JDK. It prevents to generate easily JAX-WS classes with a Maven plugin using `wsimport` under the hood.
I am using the following configuration for the Maven plugin `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <packageName>tech.myproject.service</packageName>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlLocation>/wsdl/service.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there an easy way to install wsimport or to use another plugin bundling an architecture specific wsimport to continue generating WSDL classes?

Comment: Might lead to some help - https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/67#issuecomment-425423521

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the new version of `jaxws-maven-plugin` ([link](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-maven-plugin/2.3.2/maven-plugin)) can generate Java classes with Java 11, using the plugin as follows:

```
<build>
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-java-sources</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>${project.build.directory}/generated/wsdl/MyService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
          </wsdlFiles>
          <wsdlLocation>/wsdl/MyService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

An alternative plugin can also be the cxf-codegen-plugin from Apache CXF ([link](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-codegen-plugin/3.3.1/maven-plugin))

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the newer **[JakartaEE 9.0+](https://jakarta.ee/release/9/)** packages, you need to use the following plugin, keeping the same configurations:

```
<build>
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-java-sources</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>${project.build.directory}/generated/wsdl/MyService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
          </wsdlFiles>
          <wsdlLocation>/wsdl/MyService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

and for jaxb:

```
<groupId>com.evolvedbinary.maven.mojohaus</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
```

Comment: Phase `<phase>process-classes</phase>`was breaking my build since the generated classes were not generated otherwise it's fine, thanks!

Comment: it does not generate classes with the suffix "Service" for me

Comment: This helped. had to update        from        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  -->  to
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>.
After that had to import few jakarta related dependencies.

Comment: Be careful the block `<configuration>` must be outside of block `<execution>`, it must be at the same level of `<plugin>`

Answer (score 4):

Found this - https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/54#issuecomment-440597801
I used the same configuration as for org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons jaxws-maven-plugin. Think it is the same as org.codehaus.mojo, but don't 100% sure.

Tested with JDK 11. All XSD elements, ports and services are generated.
You also need to add a few dependencies to your pom.
Minimum:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.javaee-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```